# Ошибка: The driver must be deployed to the target computer for debugging to work

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, драйвер

Ситуация такая, я пытаюсь запустить драйвер на target машине по [гайду](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows-hardware/drivers/gettingstarted/writing-a-very-small-kmdf--driver). Но получаю ошибку выше. target пк пингуется, вроде все делал тоже по [гайду](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows-hardware/drivers/gettingstarted/provision-a-target-computer-wdk-8-1) (кроме этого (непойму что делать)

```
If Secure Boot is enabled on an x86 or x64 target computer, disable it. For information about Unified Extensible Firmware Interface (UEFI) and Secure Boot, see UEFI Firmware.
If the target computer uses an ARM processor, install the Windows Debug Policy. This can be done only by Microsoft or the manufacturer of the target computer. You do not need to disable Secure Boot.
```

)
Фаероволл просто откл. Что это может быть? Если из-за того что не делал, обьясните пожалуйста как это делать, в биос наверно лезть?
Еще и target и host пк, находяться в 1 wifi сети.

Answer (score 2):

Драйвер, который вы пытаетесь установить, является модулем, загружаемым на самых ранних этапах загрузки ОС силами UEFI (современного аналога BIOS-а).

Такие модули должны иметь цифровую подпись. В вашем же случае цифровой подписи нет, поэтому вам предлагают отключить проверку этих самых подписей. Как именно — смотрите в документации по UEFI Secure Boot вашего компьютера (способы отличаются от производителя к производителю).

Comment: Т.е я так понял это из-за того что я это не сделал вот это If Secure Boot is enabled on an x86 or x64 target computer, disable it...? Спс, буду искать в Bios